# Delayed API calls with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have a simple problem. I want to make an API call for some text inside an input box. However, I want to make just one API call for the whole word, rather than one for each letter that is typed.

This can be solved by calling API after pressing a button, but I wanted to use a 1 second delay with setTimeout, where if the user types a letter within 1 second of the previous letter, the setTimeout is cleared and restarted.

Here is the sample code.

```js
document.getElementById('my_input').addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
    const x = setTimeout(()=>{
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(json => {console.log(json)})
    },5000)
})
```

This will call the API after every letter in the input. I wish to create a delay where IF the user types something again, it clears the previous timeout, so that the WHOLE input is called just ONCE when the user stops typing.

NO BUTTONS ALLOWED.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put `fetch` API part in a different function. And you can declare a global variable to assign the `setTimeout` function and clear the timer:

```
var fetchDataTimer;

function fetchData() {
    fetchDataTimer = setTimeout(()=>{
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {console.log(json)})
    },5000);
}

document.getElementById('my_input').addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
    clearTimeout(fetchDataTimer);
    fetchData();
});
```